# Trigger not working to convert 'm/d/YYY' to DATE type. REPRO included

Tags: mysql

I'm going to be bulk inserting data from a file and I'd like to be able to convert the data type using MySQL instead of the backend language.  Here's what I'm doing but it's not working and I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

```
create table t1 (TEST_DATE DATE);

DELIMITER |
create trigger t1FixDate BEFORE INSERT ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.TEST_DATE=STR_TO_DATE(NEW.TEST_DATE, '%c/%e/%Y');
END; |
DELIMITER ;

insert into t1 VALUES ('9/7/2016');
//Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '9/7/2016' for column 'TEST_DATE' at row 1
```

edit: the below SQL works.  I'm really stumped on this one.  Are triggers done before type checking??

```
create table t2 (TEST_DATE DATE);
insert into t2 VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('9/7/2016', '%c/%e/%Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html),

> The keyword BEFORE indicates the trigger action time. In this case, the trigger activates before each row inserted into the table

So, trigger works with row, which **had already been created**, but not added to the table. It means, that your string was assigned to column with data type Date, this operation failed (null was assigned).
And after that trigger was called, so it deals with null value.